# jQuery animation with setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am confused about the pauses and the seemingly erratic behaviour of the animations. The pauses are way longer than 2000ms and the animation jumps way farther then I want it to.

```
function myFunction() {
    myVar = setInterval(slideit, 2000);
}
```

I want to run a sequence of animations every 2 seconds (or 6 seconds rather, but for testing I'll go with 2) but the result seems kind of weird.

What am I doing wrong?

I am aware that I do not need callbacks for animations but the whole thing went out of sync when the window was minimized then, so I hoped that using callbacks could prevent that.

```js
var myVar;
var countit;
countit = 1;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setInterval(slideit, 2000);
}

function slideit() {
  $(".bannertext").animate({ // Text out
    opacity: 0,
    "left": "-200px"
  }, 500, function() {
    $(".imgcontainer").animate({ // Next  Image
      "top": -($(".imgcontainer").height() * countit)
    }, 500, function() {
      $(".bannertext").animate({ // Text in
        opacity: 1,
        "left": "-20px"
      }, 500);
    });
  });


  countit = countit + 1;
  if (countit == $(".imgcontainer").length) {
    countit = 1;
  }
}

myFunction();
```

```css
#banner {
  background: url(img/rauch-klein.jpg);
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 350px;
  background-size: cover;
}
#subbanner {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#banner .imgcontainer {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  height: 350px;
}
#banner img {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner">
  <div id="subbanner">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <div class="bannertext">Absaugarm 150mm</div>

      <img src="img/units/absaugarm.png" style="vertical-align:middle;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="subbanner">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <div class="bannertext">Absaugarm 200mm</div>

      <img src="img/units/absaugarm-200mm.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="subbanner">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <div class="bannertext">Absaugkran</div>

      <img src="img/units/absaugkran.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="subbanner">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <div class="bannertext">Absaugtisch</div>

      <img src="img/units/absaugtisch.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="subbanner">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <div class="bannertext">AIRTECH P10</div>

      <img src="img/units/Airtech_P10.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="subbanner">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <div class="bannertext">AIRTECH P30</div>

      <img src="img/units/Airtech_P30.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="subbanner">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <div class="bannertext">BlowTec</div>

      <img src="img/units/BlowTec.png">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: There is no problem with the code you posted. I bet there is a bug in the slideIt function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> If multiple elements are animated, the callback is executed once per
>   matched element, not once for the animation as a whole

That means the complete function is called for each bannertext class element. If you don't want to fadeout only specific elements, the quickest solution is referring to `this` inside the callback function.

```
function slideit() {

  var cnt = countit;
  $(".bannertext").animate({ // Text out
    opacity: 0,
    "left": "-200px"
  }, 500, function() {
    $(this).parent().animate({ // Next  Image
      "top": -($(".imgcontainer").height() * cnt)
    }, 500, function() {
      $(this).children(".bannertext").animate({ // Text in
        opacity: 1,
        "left": "-20px"
      }, 500);
    });
  });

  countit = countit + 1;
  if (countit == $(".imgcontainer").length) {
    countit = 1;
  }
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/1sx9qt3d/4/).

(Another side effect was that countit was increased right away. In normal execution it would have been increased before the first complete callback was executed. That's why a temp variable cnt is used as well)

Comment: Great, thanks. Can you explain the issue with the variable though? What does the temp variable do exactly?

Comment: Animate starts in its own (asynchronous) contexts, and the code is not blocked (otherwise a callback wouldn't be needed either). Therefore, after calling animate, countit is immediately updated. So the first slide will go to an increased countit (starting at 2). You could also do the increase before the call to animate and alter the indices as needed, but by using the temp variable you set the value for which slide will be used, regardless of what happens to the global variable countit after the call.